# Regular expression get substring of a word in string?

Tags: java, regex

For example, I have a string : "These is an explicit model of the spatial relationships between objects in an image."

I want to get a substring "model of the" is  preceding/succeeding words of a word "of". Can you help me suggest some regular expression?

Comment: can you share input output example?

Comment: my input is a above example.

Comment: my output is "model of the"

Comment: So you want to `find()` text which is build from `anyWord` `of` `anyWord`. There are many ways to achieve that, depending on what characters you want to accept as `anyWord`. One way could be `\w+`, which gives us `\w+ of \w+`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the character set to be as wide as possible, you can use `\S` which means `any non whitespace character`. Which gives:

```
(\S+)\s+of\s+(\S+)
```

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XBAi3N/1)